# How to make a function take a tree literal?

Tags: swift, tree

I would like to be able to pass an arbitrarily nested tuple or array to a tree builder function like this:

```
make_tree( (l: nil, v: 1, r:(l:(r: nil, v: 5, r: nil), v: 8, r: nil)) )
```

How do I write the signature for such a function?

```
func make_tree(_ tree:???) -> TreeClass
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just declare a `Node` class like this

```
class Node {
    var left: Node?
    var right: Node?
    var value: Int

    init(left: Node?, value: Int, right:Node?) {
        self.left = left
        self.right = right
        self.value = value
    }
}
```

You can then write

```
let tree = Node(left: nil, value: 1, right: Node(left: Node(left: nil, value: 5, right: nil), value: 8, right: nil))
```

### Update

You can also use a `default value` of the params of the initializer like this

```
class Node {
    var left: Node?
    var right: Node?
    var value: Int

    init(left: Node? = nil, value: Int, right:Node? = nil) {
        self.left = left
        self.right = right
        self.value = value
    }
}
```

Now you can build the same tree omitting the `left` and `right` params when you want to pass a `nil` value to them.

```
let tree = Node(value: 1, right: Node(left: Node(value: 5), value: 8))
```

Comment: I think enums would be a better way to go about this, because they would remove much the need for optionals. I'll whip up an example.

Answer (score 1):

I would use an enum for this.

```
class Tree<T> {
    var root: Node<T>
    init(_ root: Node<T>) { self.root = root}
}

indirect enum Node<T> {
    case branch(Node, value: T, Node)
    case leftBranch(left: Node, value: T)
    case rightBranch(value: T, right: Node)
    case leaf(value: T)
}

func makeTree() -> Tree<Int> {
    return Tree(.rightBranch(value: 1, right:
        .leftBranch(left: .leaf(value: 5), value: 8)))
}
```

Comment: Very interesting.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply parse dictionary literal.

```
class TreeClass {
    var left: TreeClass?
    var right: TreeClass?
    var value: Int

    init(left: TreeClass?, right: TreeClass?, value: Int) {
        self.left = left
        self.right = right
        self.value = value
    }
}

extension TreeClass {
    enum Key {
        case left
        case right
        case value
    }
}

func makeTree(_ tree: [TreeClass.Key: Any]) -> TreeClass {
    var left: TreeClass?
    var right: TreeClass?
    var value: Int?
    for (key, dictValue) in tree {
        switch (key, dictValue) {
        case (.left, let nodeValue as [TreeClass.Key: Any]):
            assert(left == nil)
            left = makeTree(nodeValue)
        case (.right, let nodeValue as [TreeClass.Key: Any]):
            assert(right == nil)
            right = makeTree(nodeValue)
        case (.value, let intValue as Int):
            assert(value == nil)
            value = intValue
        default:
            fatalError()
        }
    }
    assert(value != nil)
    return TreeClass(left: left, right: right, value: value!)
}

let v = TreeClass.Key.value
let r = TreeClass.Key.right
let l = TreeClass.Key.left

let tree = makeTree([v: 1, r: [l: [v: 5], v: 8]])
```

I have also tried to use `ExpressibleByDictionaryLiteral` or `ExpressibleByArrayLiteral`, but some parts of them looked so ugly for me.

And frankly, I, myself, would write something like appzYourLife's, which is type-safe, simple and easy to understand.